# How to concatenate geometries?

Tags: postgis

I use the sql below it returns me several geom_way:

```
SELECT St_astext(geom)FROM pgr_fromAtoB('ways',-51.1995,-30.0487604,-51.2157942,-30.0469069);
```

Return:

```
LINESTRING(-51.1995 -30.0487604,-51.2010166 -30.0495917)
LINESTRING(-51.2010166 -30.0495917,-51.2025687 -30.0503647)
LINESTRING(-51.2025687 -30.0503647,-51.2038761 -30.0510814)
LINESTRING(-51.2038761 -30.0510814,-51.2052346 -30.0517926)
LINESTRING(-51.2052346 -30.0517926,-51.2053382 -30.0517299,-51.2055086 -30.0514995)
LINESTRING(-51.2055086 -30.0514995,-51.2065542 -30.052029)
LINESTRING(-51.2065542 -30.052029,-51.2070887 -30.0518558,-51.2074272 -30.0517254)
LINESTRING(-51.2074272 -30.0517254,-51.2081763 -30.0514558)
LINESTRING(-51.2081763 -30.0514558,-51.208337 -30.0513539,-51.20844 -30.0512648,-51.2085687 -30.0511236,-51.2088256 -30.0507909,-51.2090106 -30.0505536)
LINESTRING(-51.2090106 -30.0505536,-51.2098613 -30.0494869,-51.2100104 -30.0494252)
LINESTRING(-51.2100104 -30.0494252,-51.2102327 -30.0494958,-51.2108592 -30.0498549)
LINESTRING(-51.2108592 -30.0498549,-51.2116327 -30.0494558)
LINESTRING(-51.2116327 -30.0494558,-51.2130232 -30.0486757)
LINESTRING(-51.2130232 -30.0486757,-51.2133473 -30.048497)
LINESTRING(-51.2133473 -30.048497,-51.2134741 -30.0478809,-51.2135209 -30.0477931)
LINESTRING(-51.2135209 -30.0477931,-51.2136382 -30.0478068)
LINESTRING(-51.2136382 -30.0478068,-51.2136545 -30.0477302,-51.2136611 -30.0476998)
LINESTRING(-51.2136611 -30.0476998,-51.2137138 -30.047454)
LINESTRING(-51.2137138 -30.047454,-51.2137818 -30.047341)
LINESTRING(-51.2137818 -30.047341,-51.213891 -30.0473541,-51.2147429 -30.0474634)
LINESTRING(-51.2147429 -30.0474634,-51.214929 -30.0467988)
LINESTRING(-51.214929 -30.0467988,-51.2157942 -30.0469069)
```

I try:

```
SELECT ST_Union(St_astext(geom))FROM pgr_fromAtoB('ways',-51.1995,-30.0487604,-51.2157942,-30.0469069);
```

But returned a geometry .. I need the lat / long

```
010500000016000000010200000002000000A8C64B37899949C00257C38F7B0C3EC0007A75E9BA9949C02EA7A90AB20C3EC0010200000002000000BCD86AC5ED9949C0735F73B3E40C3EC0D0F7AE9C189A49C0146FAEAB130D3EC001020000000300000038C2FDDBC09A49C0F0B1AA14F10C3EC018192EBCDC9A49C09714692CAB0C3EC0F2E8EB9EE19A49C028994121A70C3EC0010200000002000000007A75E9BA9949C02EA7A90AB20C3EC0BCD86AC5ED9949C0735F73B3E40C3EC001020000000....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think moving the `St_AsText()` call to the outermost part of your query accomplish what you want

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Union(geom)) FROM pgr_fromAtoB('ways',-51.1995,-30.0487604,-51.2157942,-30.0469069);
```